# Bounding a series of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Suppose that $X,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are iid random variables with $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$. Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that
>   $$
> P\biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|X_n|I_{\{|X_n|>n^{1/p}\}}<C\biggr)=1,
> $$
>   where $I_A$ is the indicator function of an event $A$?

We have that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|>n^{1/p})\le\operatorname E|X|^P<\infty.
$$
Hence, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the series contains only a finite number of non-zero elements almost surely. There exists $\Omega_0\subset\Omega$ such that $P(\Omega_0)=1$ and for each $\omega\in\Omega_0$ we have $C(\omega)$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|X_n(\omega)|I_{\{|X_n|>n^{1/p}\}}(\omega)<C(\omega).
$$
But this bound depends on $\omega$. If we took $C=\sup_{\omega\in\Omega_0}C(\omega)$, this bound might not be finite, right? So it seems that we cannot bound this series with probability $1$ by a single constant $C>0$. Is that corrrect?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If $P(|X|>x)>0$ for every $x$, there exists no such $C$ since $|X_1|>C$ implies the sum of the series is $>C$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no constant that bounds the sum for all $\omega$. The event
\begin{align}
|X_n| > n^{1/p} &&\forall n\le N
\end{align}
has positive probability for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, lets call it $p_N$. Then for each bound $C$ there exists a $N>C$ for which there is a set of $\omega$'s of size at least $p_N$ such that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|X_n|I_{\{X_n>n^{1/p}\}} \ge N > C.
$$

Comment: The first event does not necessarily have a positive probability. Take, for example, iid Bernoulli random variables. Then the probability is zero.

Comment: Ah right, I assumed a full domain for $X$.